# Which part of my matlab code is multi-threaded?

Tags: multithreading, matlab

Is there a way to do some profiling to check which part of my code uses several thread?

I have a matlab code, where I run it, I can see on the system monitor that several cores are used. But I cannot figure out which part of the code is multi-threaded...

I wonder if the profiler can find it out, or some other tool...

Comment: any particular reason why you would like to find out?

Comment: @Ashish That's because I run this code on my lab's cluster. And I need to book some cores. If my consumption of cores vary with time, either I book several cores, and some cores will be unused at some point, or I book only one core, and my lab mates will be unpleased that my jobs take CPU time from them.

Comment: You could use the -singleCompThread option to MATLAB to ensure you only use a single core.

Comment: Is it possible to use -singleCompThread on a compiled (with mcc) matlab script?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-46OY0H/?solution=1-46OY0H (Which I take to mean, if you start MATLAB with the -singleCompThread, and then compile an application, it will deploy as a single threaded one. You could try an experiment to confirm)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A round about way, is to search for known multi-threaded functions.  Here's the best list I know of for that: http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=1894.  Also note that operations like, a.*b, or sin(a) will be multi-threaded if a and/or b are large enough matrices.

You can also use the profiler to reduce your search space.  If most of your code is running multi-threaded most of the time, then wherever your code is spending time the most is likely where the multi-threading is occurring....

Comment: Thank you, that'll help a lot. +1